# How to rebase on top of staging even when local master is multiple commits behind from remote?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am rebasing feature branch into origin/staging with this code `

```
git rebase -i origin/staging
```

After successfully rebasing feature branch , in gitlab it shows `

> Request to merge feature into staging (1 commit behind)

So this scenario forces me to rebase again, but first pulling from staging and then again the same rebasing workflow.

Is there any possible way to rebase on top of staging regardless of how many commits it's behind from staging.

Comment: Between two rebases, someone else might have pushed and updated the branch in the remote repository.

Comment: So what you want is to `rebase` onto `staging` without having to checkout first, then pull? Then checkout feature and rebase onto `staging`?

Comment: You're rebasing on `origin/staging`, not on `origin/master`. If you run `git fetch` before you begin, you'll have an up-to-date `origin/staging` and `origin/master`, although if you take 20 minutes to rebase, that gives other people 20 minutes to get in ahead of you.

Comment: I edited ,  yes not master , but staging ... Typo ... Yes i know i can fetch all and then make rebase , and i do it everytime , but sometimes it gives 1 commit behind , so i would like to rebase on top of staging regardless of commits behind

Comment: You can leave your branch untouched, but cant stop other people from updating remote repository `git checkout feature` `git fetch origin/staging`
`git rebase -i origin/staging`